# Getting error while searching content item in sitecore

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore

[image]

I am unable to find any item from item tree even though item is already exist.

Comment: did you try to rebuild the indexes ?

Comment: Yes i tried.but getting same issue.The problem is permission.

ie:

I have 3 sites
Site1
 .Item

Site2
 .Item

Site3
 .Item

A admin can have access only for Site1 and searching item in Site1.but throwing error because he does not have permission for remaining two sites and templates.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look at the exception message in the log file first.

If you log in as a Sitecore Administrator and perform the same search, does it also throw an error?

Comment: I logged in as a administrator and tried but i haven't faced any issue,working fine.but,when i logged in as a site specific user returning error.

Comment: Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.Pipelines.Search.SearchContentSearchIndex.Process(SearchArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Search.Instant.InstantSearch.DoSearch(String query)
at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Search.Instant.InstantSearch.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()

Comment: And does it work when you use the search button next to the Folder & Content buttons on the right?
That one works differently from the Tree search... so perhaps its a workaround

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with your sitecore content search configuration file. Make sure you are using the following type:

`<configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">`

and

`Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider"` (for the index type)

in all your index configuration files, including the default sitecore ones:

1. Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Core.config
2. Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Master.config
3. Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Web.config

Moreover,

- rebuild all your indexes including the Core, Master and Web.
- rebuild the Search index from the Control Panel:

  Control Panel -> Database -> Rebuild the Link Database

  Control Panel -> Database -> Rebuild the Search Index

Comment: Followed all above mentioned steps.but still facing issue.for administrator returning expected value. but a non-administrator user unable to search.

Comment: try to set the value of the LegacySearchEngine to true. It is found in the Sitecore.ContentSearch.config 
`<setting name="Search.UseLegacySearchEngine" value="true"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Please try checking the permissions of the folder where the indexes are.  Sometimes it is this trivial and simple.